# How to automatically delete Campaign Members using a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, leads, automation, campaign-member

So, I am developing a record triggered flow that will create or delete campaign members depending on the status of 5 custom checkboxes in the Lead object, so, when the checkboxes are ticked or unticked, that lead is added or removed from the corresponding campaign.

So far it is creating the Campaign Members with no issues, however, I can't get it to delete existing records when the checkboxes are updated.

These are the entry conditions: [image: Start conditions 1]

[[image: Start Conditions 22]

Then I decide whether the flow is going to create a campaign member or delete it:
[image: Getting Campaign Ids]

These are the conditions for creating: [image: Creating records] and deleting [image: deleting records]

Then, for each branch I ask if the lead needs to be added or deleted from each campaign, a lead can be added or deleted from multiple campaigns at the same time:
[image: Decision branches]

Focusing on the deletion branch, this is how I'm asking if a specific checkbox was unchecked:
[image: Asking if the APAC checkbox is False]

And if that condition is met, I'm looking for the campaign member with that Lead and Campaign ID, and storing that ID in a collection variable

[image: Get records to delete]

I'm using that collection variable to store the campaign members of the 5 campaigns and then using a delete records element at the end of the flow to delete the records [image: Deleting records]

Since both branches are pretty similar, I guess the delete records part is the one that is not working, but I don't see how, I really appreciate any guidance.

This is how the delete records part is set up: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried creating a flow and ran into the same issue. Here's an article detailing the known issue: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k7MAAQ/record-triggered-flow-not-invoked-on-bulk-delete

I'll let you know if I find a resolution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196029)